# SQL Server Stored Procedure Combining 2 table results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

**CustomerTransaction**

```
Id (int auto int)
CustomerName (varchar)
CustomerNumber (int)
Date (date)
WeeklyAmount (int)
```

**Customers**:

```
CustomerName (varchar)
CustomerNumber (int)
CustomerType (int)
CustomerDate (date)
```

This database is not normalized, and I can not change it. The `CustomerName` and what I need to do:

I need a result that will show one table with all of the information from `Customers` for each row that matches customer number. In `CustomerTransaction`, I am merely grouping all of the total sums per `CustomerName` of their amount.

I am using:

```
Select
    CustomerNumber, SUM (WeeklyAmount) as Total 
from  
    Customers.RECORDS 
GROUP BY 
    CustomerNumber;
```

To get the sum of each `CustomerNumber`. The problem is that I can not include `CustomerName` in the group by. Sometimes the name of customers change over time. I was told to grab the data from `Customers` and it to the result above and match the `CustomerNumbers`

The problem is that I do not know that with a stored procedure. Anyone know how this is done?
I need all the rows matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
CustomerNumber, SUM (WeeklyAmount) as Total from  
Customers.RECORDS GROUP BY CustomerNumber;
```

What is `Customers.RECORDS`? That's a bit confusing. Apart from that, I'd answer

```
SELECT 
c.*,
sq.Total
FROM
(
SELECT 
CustomerNumber,
SUM(WeeklyAmount) AS Total
FROM 
CustomersTransaction
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
) sq
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerNumber = sq.CustomerNumber
```

If that's not what you're looking for, you have to rephrase your question. It's a bit hard to understand where the actual problem is. Usually I'd write the query a bit different, but this should deal with the non-normalization issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Trans.CustomerNumber, C.CustomerName, Trans.SUM (WeeklyAmount) as Total
from  
CustomerTransaction Trans
join
 Customers C
on
Trans.CustomerNumber=C.CustomerNumber
GROUP BY 
Trans.CustomerNumber,C.CustomerName
```